# update div content through Ajax in php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am making edit functionality in website and using ajax to update the div, here is my code.

```
<?php  echo '<div class="products_data" id="servicedata' . $i . '">
                        <label id="servicename' . $i . '">' . $ser_name [$i] .                       '</label><div class="edit" style="display: none; margin-top:12px;margin-left: -20px;"><a   onclick="editService(' . $i . ')"><img alt="edit_icon" src="images/edit-icon.png"    class="edit_link edit"></a></div>
                        <p><a href = "' . urldecode ( $ser ['data'] [$i] [0] ['data']    ['url'] ) . '" id="serviceurl' . $i . '">' . urldecode ( $ser ['data'] [$i] [0] ['data'] ['url'] ) . '</a></p>
                            <p>';
                        $str = base64_decode ( $ser ['data'] [$i] [0] ['data']      ['description'] );
                        echo '<div id="servicedescription'.$i.'">' . $str . '</div>';

                        echo '</p></div>';?>
```

and my ajax function is:

var t;

```
function updateServices(t)
{
var vse = "#serviceedit"+t;
var vsd = "#servicedata"+t;
var div = "servicedata"+t;
var vsne = "serviceNameedit"+t;
var vsue = "serviceURLedit"+t;
var vsde = "serviceDescriptionedit"+t;
var service = "service"+t;
var tno = t;
var sne = document.getElementById(vsne).value;
var sue = document.getElementById(vsue).value;
var sde = document.getElementById(vsde).value;
var srvc = document.getElementById(service).value;
$.ajax({
    url: "./handler/serviceEdit_process.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        COMPANY:<?php echo '"'.$company.'"';?>,
        editserName: sne,
        editserURL: sue,
        editserDescription: sde,
        service: srvc,
        TNO: tno
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(vse);
        alert(vsd);
        $(vse).css("display","none");
        $(vsd).css("display","block");
        $(div).empty();
        $(div).html(data);
    }
});
```

My div is updating only after page reloading, I want to update div within a page.

Comment: please alert "data" in success part. Is it blank or display some values ?

Comment: if you are using jquery as it seems , then why getElmentById, and also check error in console of browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent the browser following the link:

```
<a   onclick="event.preventDefault(); editService(' . $i . ')">
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event, t ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Do your stuff here...
    });
});
```